# Drag and Drop the id of a model in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, drag-and-drop, marionette

I'm trying to drag and drop only the id for a model of a card on the screen.  So the first part of this is setting the id using setData() on the event.
I have made the card element in the card's template have the attribute draggable="true".  When I click to drag the card I get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setData' of undefined

```
var CardView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: tmpl,
    events: {
        'dragstart .card-container': 'dragStart',
    },
    dragStart: function (e) {
        e.dataTransfer.setData("Text", this.model.id);
    },
});

return CardView;
});
```

I'm using Google Chrome, Backbone.js w/ Marionette

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the data like this:

`e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('Text', this.model.id);`

This is because Backbone is hooking up the event using jQuery, and `e` is a [jQuery event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) object.